# Is there a way to install the windows 64 bit drivers on my windows 32 bit

Tags: windows-7, drivers, 64-bit, 32-bit, win32

So, I know that I am asking an impossible thing but I think that there should be a way for that. Can I install 64bit windows7 drivers to a 32 bit windows 7 computer. Is there any way that can convert the drivers to a 32bit supported OS.

> Note that I am talking about Operating System, not a processor<

OK, I know that there are emulators but the emulators have software in there description but I am asking about drivers. Many people have this problem when they download but sized drivers and afterwards they note that they are made up for 64bit only. I have only 2 GB of RAM so answer a way that it shouldn't make my system lagging. Please help. If any correction or details needed, comment it below.
THANK YOU

Answer (score 4):

> Can I install a 64-bit `Windows 7` device driver on a 32-bit version of `Windows 7`?

**No;** This isn't possible.  There isn't anything you can enable that would make this possible.

> Is there any way that can convert the drivers to a 32-bit supported OS.

If you had the source to the drivers you could do this.

> OK, I know that there are emulators but the emulators have software in
>   there description but I am asking about drivers.

An emulator wouldn't be helpful in a case like this.  You could in theory use a virtual machine and install a 64-bit installation of Windows within that and use the device while its connected to the virtual machine provided its a USB device.

> Many people have this problem when they download but sized drivers and
>   afterwards they note that they are made up for 64-bit only.

Why don't you just use the 32-bit version of the driver?